# Android. Как запустить из потока thread диалоговое окно AlertDialog?

Tags: android, многопоточность

Добрый день!

Возникла задача создать в Android-приложении дополнительный поток для работы в фоновом режиме. Нужно после выполнения длительной задачи в потоке запустить AlertDialog с результатами задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю запустить диалог можно только из главного потока. Если у вас есть ссылка на активити то можно сделать таким образом

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //показать диалог
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Фоновый поток запускайте через `AsyncTask<>`, после окончания фоновой задачи `AsyncTask` дает возможность использовать хэндлер `onPostExecute()`, в котором спокойно можно вызвать `AlertDialog`, чтобы сообщить юзеру результат выполнения задачи.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш совет. Воспользовался AsyncTask и все заработало!